# Angular - modify observable value

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a function in my `angular` component that receives an observable. I need to modify the object inside the observable and then 'put it back inside' the observable again and return it. This is my code so far:

```
myImmobili =  Observable<Valutazione[]>;
newImmobile(immobili: Observable<Valutazione[]>) {

    immobili.subscribe(
      imm => { 
        console.log(imm);
        imm.push(new Valutazione());
        console.log(imm);
        this.myImmobili = //some code here
      }
    );
  }
```

Can anyone give me a hint? Maybe there's even a better way to modify my array without subscribing to it, but I couldn't find it. Thanks.

EDIT

```
newImmobile() {

    this.immobili.subscribe(i => console.log('before', i));
    this.immobili.map(imm => {
      imm.push(new Valutazione());
      console.log('inside', imm);
    }
    );
    this.immobili.subscribe(i => console.log('after', i));
  }
```

Now it skips completely the map function. The logs 'before' and 'after' shows the same array, and the 'inside log' doesn't show.

Comment: Do you want to change whole object or just modify the values of array based on some condition?

Comment: Only the values of the array, as I'm doing inside the subscribe() call. I need to return an Observable that contains the modified array.

Comment: Use 'map' operator to change the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subscribing you can use map:

```
immobili.map(
  imm => { 
    console.log(imm);
    imm.push(new Valutazione());
    console.log(imm);
    this.myImmobili = //some code here
  }
);
```

Comment: I changed my code as you and @Basavaraj Bhusani suggest but it skips completely the map operator execution.

Comment: you need to subscribe atleast once at the end point. You can't use only map. it has to be coupled with subscribe.

Comment: That was it. Thanks.